# QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem in freeze application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have created a PyQGIS MapViewer application. When I run from Pycharm everything is OK. When I run CMD from the command line (without Pycharm) everything is OK. But when I create a separate application (freeze - exe), the problem is from

```
self.myCanvas = QgsMapCanvas(self)
self.crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857')
print(self.crs)
```

<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: invalid>

Comment: is `proj` installed outside of PyCharm?

Comment: I do not open some project. Projekt is creating inside application and do not saving.

Comment: `proj` is the library that provides QGIS projection information, you probably want to make sure [`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) is installed and working correctly where you run your script

Comment: And shouldn't QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem be part of qgis.core ??

Comment: I never used "pyproj" before freezing.

Comment: It's part of your qgis install, when running outside qgis you will need to provide it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. You know how to navigate me closer than I do. Well thank you.

Comment: And what do you use to create an exe application. I use cx_Freeze.

Comment: i managed to add pyproj to the "lib" library but it didn't help.

Comment: Hello, I already solved this problem by editing setup.py in cx_Freeyze.
By adding additional libraries:

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem by editing setup.py in cx_Freeyze.
By adding additional libraries:

```
files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join(projsharepath, "*.*")), new_folder=r"lib\proj")
    files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join(qgisbin, "*.dll")))
    files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join(qgisroot, "plugins", "*.dll")), new_folder=r"lib\qgis\plugins")
    files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join(qgisresources, "*.db")), new_folder=r"lib\qgis\resources")
    utils = ['ogr2ogr.exe', 'ogrinfo.exe', 'gdalinfo.exe', 'NCSEcw.dll', "spatialite.dll"]
    extrafiles = [os.path.join(osgeobin, path) for path in utils]
    files += format_paths(extrafiles)
    files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join(gdallibpath, "gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll")))
    files += format_paths(glob.glob(os.path.join("lib", "*.dll")), new_folder="lib\qgis")
```